# React Native display FlatList with Firebase data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Trying to get FlatList to display data from Firebase.
Setup is correct and I can see the date in my console, but don't know how to visualise it.

I'd like to see 'recipeOne' 'recipeTwo' 'recipeThree' in the list.
I am sure I am missing something basic.

Here is the code

```
...

import {DataConfig} from '../data/DataConfig';
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(DataConfig);

globalTexts = require('../styles/Texts.js');
globalColors = require('../styles/Colors.js');

export default class ListSort extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.dataItem = firebaseApp.database().ref('recipes');
      this.state = {
         item: []
      }
   };

   componentWillMount() {
      this._createItemList();
   };

   _createItemList = (dataItem) => {
      this.dataItem.on('value', (snapshot) => {
         var itemList = [];
         snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            itemList.push({
               key:doc.key,
               itemType: doc.toJSON()
            });
            this.setState({item: itemList});
            console.log(this.state.item);
         })
      })
   };

   render() {
      return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
               data={this.state.item}
               renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                  <View style={styles.cell}>
                     <Text style={globalText.btnFlatPrimary}>{item.recipes}</Text>
                  </View>
               )}
            />
         </View>
      )
   }
}
```

and here is the data. The rules in Firebase are setup as read:true only.

```
{
"recipes": {
    "recipeOne": {...
    "recipeTwo": {...
    "recipeThree": {...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more detail about the data being returned. Right now it looks like you're trying to reference `item.recipes`, but item only has key & itemType as properties.

Comment: Try to log the content of item in your `renderItem` that will help and same for `console.log(this.state.item);`

Comment: @MattyK14 you'r right, I didn't finish editing references. Should be fine now

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how the firebase snapshot works anymore it's been a while, but hopefully this snack can help you a bit: https://snack.expo.io/SkjfQuHYz

Comment: @CladClad Thanks, I can see the data in the console, but not sure ho to display it.

Comment: @MattyK14 That brilliant, I'll have a look through. thanks

Comment: show us the result of the console and we will find out why it isn't showing :3

Comment: It works now, code is not elegant, but for now it'll do. The solution was to map the objects coming from the data.


`_createItemList = (dataItem) => {
    ...
    const itemsName = itemList.map(key => {})`